# How to resolve the error in pentaho datagrid?

Tags: datagrid, pentaho

I have entered the datetype for the column cust-id as integer but i am facing the error as could not convert the string as integer.

**cust_id String : couldn't convert String to number : non-numeric character found at position 5 for value**

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check for trailing white space.

Other possibility: is the character on position 5 a dot or comma? Does it match the decimal separator of your locale? If your locale uses a comma for decimal separator and you enter a dot (or vice versa) it throws an error.